# Sorting matrixblocks by earliest date from child table

Tags: templating, matrix, sorting

I have a matrix field (events), each of this blocks (event) contains a table (dates) with individual rows (date), those have a start date and a start time. I would like to sort the events (matrix blocks) by the earliest start date / start time. Also at some point I would only want to display future events.

Whats the "best" way to achieve this kind of sorting in a template (twig)? Would I have to loop through them and sort them "manually"? I think about something around sorting the child tables first and then sort the blocks by their first table rows.

**Entry**

- Event A [*matrixblock*]

  - Dates [*table*]

    - Date 1 | (12/12/2015) [*datetimefield*] | (10:00) [*datetimefield*]
    - Date 2 | (10/10/2015) [datetimefield] | (10:00) [*datetimefield*]
- Event B [matrixblock]

  - Dates [table]

    - Date 1 | (09/09/2015) [*datetimefield*] | (10:00) [*datetimefield*]
    - Date 2 | (10/10/2015) [*datetimefield*] | (10:00) [*datetimefield*]
    - Date 3 | (11/11/2015) [*datetimefield*] | (10:00) [*datetimefield*]

This simple case would sort Event B, Event A. Because of the earliest date being Date 1 of Event B.

Appreciate any input. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit tricky to do from the template, but what I would suggest is to query for the Matrix blocks once,
than loop through the blocks and store the data to a new custom array.

The idea is, to build that array in a way that ensures, you can later apply `sort` and `group` Twig filters.

```
{% set allDates = [] %}
{% for block in entry.myEventsMatrix %}
    {% for row in block.myDatesTable %}

        {% set allDates = allDates|merge([{
            datetime: (row.myDateTime|date('c')),
            eventId: (block.id),
            event: block
        }]) %}

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

When sorting an array of arrays with the `sort` filter, the inner array's first value is relevant, so make sure this is the
DateTime you want to sort by. Besides that, I included the block's ID "eventID" and the complete block model "event".

```
{% set datesGrouped = allDates|sort|group('eventId') %}

{% for eventId, datesInEvent in datesGrouped %}
    <h3>{{ eventId }}</h3>        
    {% for date in datesInEvent %}
        {{ date.datetime|date('Y-m-d') }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Outside the "datesInEvent" loop you can access the events model with:

```
{% set event = datesInEvent[0].event %}
```

Comment: Cheers @carcls, I went with the approach you suggested. Works just fine for my case.